# When do I get some taxes from my Stronghold?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I put quite a bit of money into restoring Caed Nua, and I was under the impression that I would be able to collect some taxes in return. But so far it doesn't seem like I earned any income from my Stronghold. I checked in the treasury chest, but it was empty.

Do I have to build a specific upgrade or wait longer to collect some taxes?

Comment: Wait longer, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

I got my first tax payment about a month after acquiring the stronghold (600 at level 25 prestige and security)

Comment: After further playing, I noticed on the stronghold log that the taxes come in every 5 turns. I believe that a turns increase as you finish quests.

Answer (score -3):

*(Spoiler alert kind of)*

The exact moment I started receiving taxes was as soon as I finished the
**"Never Far from the Queen"** Quest.
Specifically, I got the update as soon as I defeated all of those shrouded people that were performing some ceremony in the main chamber in the Temple of Woedica.

Not saying that taxes were somehow tied to that moment directly, but it was how it happened.

My Stronghold stats were:

```
Prestige: 23   
Security: 33
```

And the most recent construction completed was the **Warden's Lodge** and **Training Grounds.**

Other than that, the only other thing that seems relevant was that it happend on Turn 5.

Whatever Turn 5 is.

Comment: This seems to be wrong. I received taxes before I even set foot into the Temple of Woedica yet. I am not 100% sure but I think I got my first tax payment even before I got to Defiance Bay.